# Not able to render customer details on screen using Next.js 13 / Stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a component to render basic details for a customer from Stripe, using Next.js 13 - it's for project to display a basic customer's area for an e-commerce site.

So far, I am able to query my Stripe setup, and can see the results piped to the console in my editor, but I am struggling to render `testdetails` in my component:

```
import React from "react";
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "<MY STRIPE SECRET>"
);

async function retrieveCustomer() {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.search({
    query: `email:'email.test@outlook.me'`,
  });
  console.log(customer);
}

const testdetails = retrieveCustomer();
```

This is where things are failing:

```
const Account = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is the Your Account page</p>
      <p>Name: {testdetails} </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;
```

I've tried various things, including passing `testdetails` as a prop, and using string interpolation to render, but to no avail - I feel I'm missing something stupid! I keep getting this error:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Can anyone please help point me in the right direction? I'm still a little new to using Stripe's API...!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return your customer info, and you should use useeffect to get the customer info on load (or u can do onClick of a button)

```
// I'm quite sure this part is serverside, 
// not client side, can u look at docs 
// again please?
async function retrieveCustomer() {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.search({
    query: `email:'alex.test@outlook.me'`,
  });
  console.log(customer);
  return customer // u need to return here.
}


const Account = () => {
  const [ details, setDetails ] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
      (async() => {
           const results = await retrieveCustomer();
           setDetails(results)
  
      })()

  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is the Your Account page</p>
      <p>Name: {JSON.stringify(details)} </p> string
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;
```

I do think u did abit wrong with retrieveCustomer though. stripe.customers.search should be serverside is it not?

**edit:** Since you are using nextjs /app directory, then a server component make sense. You can try this. (not recommended since this is an authenticated area, and should not be cached)

```
async function retrieveCustomer() {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.search({
    query: `email:'alex.test@outlook.me'`,
  });
  console.log(customer);
  return customer // u need to return here.
}


const Account = () => {
  const details = await retrieveCustomer();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is the Your Account page</p>
      <p>Name: {JSON.stringify(details)} </p> string
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;
export const revalidate = 0
```

`{JSON.stringify(details)}` will display your customer object. Once you know the object structure then u can replace it with something like `details.name`

Comment: Thanks for this - your changes make sense. I'm a little puzzled though, as I know I've been able to display details from Stripe - they were in my editor's console area though, which makes me think that this was happening clientside? I know there is a 'use client' option in Next.js 13 - I was wondering if I could use it something like this:
```
"use client";
const stripe = require("stripe")(<MY KEY>);
export default async function GetCustomer() {
  let customer = await stripe.customers.search({
    query: `email:'alex.test@outlook.me'`,
  });
  return customer;
}
```

Comment: I would then call it like this:
```
const Account = () => (
  <div>
    <p>This is the Your Account page</p>
    <p>Name: XXXXXX</p>
    <GetCustomer />
  </div>
);

export default Account;
```
Trouble is, I get this error instead: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Argh...any ideas/thoughts please?

Comment: If you are displaying the page as a server component then your code make sense. I will edit the answer for u. However this is a very basic usage of server component. It gets more complicated once you add in authentication. In most cases, we will use 'use client' and fetch customer details (like first example) using api (auth with cookies, jwt or iron-session).

Comment: I've given your latest edit a try - unfortunately this didn't work for me, I'm afraid :-( I had to add an `async` to the opening tag of the Account component, as it was complaining that it was missing - this then gave: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: I've even tried playing with cookies (using 2-3 different packages), but that didn't help either - I'm not sure I'm going to be able to do what I want! My original intention was to prove that the page could be protected and accessible if logged in - this I can do. I wanted to provide something from Stripe, to give a little more realism than just a text message, but I suspect that is all I will be able to do (for now). I don't think my site is using the app folder though - it's not specified as such in next.config.js, and it's not present in the site. Thanks for trying though - any more ideas?

Comment: If you are trying to do authentication with nextjs, please either implement JWT login, or iron-session, and recreate your question. This question lacks too many details.